# How do I get current Solar datetime on the Windows 10 command line?

Tags: windows, datetime, batch-file, command-line

Is there any windows command that get Current Date in Solar format

for example `1396-11-28`

I'm using Windows 10

Comment: How do you calculate the Solar datetime? I Googled "solar date format" and  found an incredible amount of conflicting information, none of which matches the format in your post.

Comment: https://www.taghvim.com/converter/

Comment: Batch doesn't have anything like this, but it looks like C# has a PersianCalendar class, which means you can use a PowerShell script: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/62f3b96b-1f15-4459-9055-805677c958fc

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/datetime/working-with-calendars

Answer (score 1):

It,s simple. Change windows locale to Persian(Control panel), restart your PC and windows show all datetime in persian format. use get-date command. Also use current datetime that shown in windows tray. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-date?view=powershell-6

Comment: .Net framework 4.5 or higher required for persian datetime inn winows tray